# angular 4 | app.component.html content is not displaying

Tags: html, angular

My basic angular app is not displaying the `app.component.html` content on `localhost:4200`. It displays blank but when I add something in `<app-root> </app-root>`, it displays. But according to tutorial websites, the data present in `component.html` should be displayed. Please help, I'm new to angular.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app 3';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project3</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root> 
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error in console:

[image]

Comment: Can you add code of your app.component.ts and app.component.html. Images you have added are not visible

Comment: added code, extremely sorry for that.

Comment: you getting any error on console??

Comment: show app.module file

Comment: I am getting this : 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)
combinecommon.es5.js:2934 webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js

Answer (score 0):

Using an outdated Angular version causes this bug.

Comment: But I see the conent of pacakage.json it says..
 "@angular/cli": "1.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",

Comment: running .. let's see

Comment: can You please add result of testing?

Comment: ng test ran successfully, it threw error in export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app 3'; >> should be 'app'
}

I changed that but still localhost is showing it blank and ng test shows success with app.component.html body

Comment: in Your app.module.ts: replace these two lines I hope it would help:  `import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Comment: wait.. it did not work in IE 11, and chromium..   but it did work in Chrome latest version, with no console errors. I did not anticipate angular's behavior to be so different in different browsers

Comment: that's great :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154277/discussion-between-salim-ibrogimov-and-sak).